# Filtering items on the backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, mern

I am filtering my items from the backend by query object which takes : brand,size,price.
Then I skip and limit ( pagination ) the list that I got.
Now the problem is when I want to filter by price in my app I got a slider which gets two values in array, example: [199,800] so I want to get all products between that range.

This is how I tried to do that:

```
getProductsPagination: async (
  _,
  { page, productsFiltersInput: { size, brand, price, color } }
) => {
  const query = {};
  if (size) {
    query.size = size;
  }
  if (brand) {
    query.brand = brand;
  }
  if (color) {
    query.color = color;
  }

  let products;
  const skip = (page - 1) * 12;
  const limit = 12;
  const totalItems = await Product.countDocuments(query);
  const pages = Math.ceil(totalItems / limit);

  products = await Product.find(query).skip(skip).limit(limit);
  if (products.length > 0) {
    products = products.filter(
      (x) => x.price > price[0] && x.price < price[1]
    );
  }

  return { products, numOfPages: pages };
},
```

The problem here as you can guess I am getting the products between that price range but I get them in seperate pages. I get 3 items in that range each item on each page which I don't want to. I want them to be all in same page. Now I know what I am doing wrong but I am really don't know how to continue from here. would like to get some hints!

Comment: are you using mongodb. you can use sort().skip().limit() in mongo

Comment: Hi , yes I am using mongodb. Sort can return me the items that the price that greater then filter price [0] and lesser than filter price [1] ?

Comment: Sort is useful here when I am trying to sort the items by the highest price \ lower price. Here I want to filter the products by the price the user is entering in the slider like: [100,499] so it will give him all the products with that range of price.

Comment: It's work but It won't get limit and skip. so I need to find better approach then what I wrote

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed this.
For those who wondering, I added to my query this:

```
 if (price.length > 0) {
        query.price = { $gte: price[0], $lte: price[1] };
      }
```

and

```
products = await Product.find(query).sort().skip(skip).limit(limit);
```